# Big-Oh Notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

I seem to be confused by a question.

Here's the question, followed by my assumptions:

*Al and Bob are arguing about their algorithms.  Al claims his O(n log n)-time method is always faster than Bob’s O(n^2)-time method.  To settle the issue, they perform a set of experiments.  To Al’s dismay, they find that if n<100, the O(n^2)-time algorithm runs faster, and only when n>= 100 is the O(n log n)-time one better.  Explain how this is possible.*

Based on what I understand, an algorithm written in an O(n^2)-time method is effective only for small amounts of input n. As the input increases, the efficiency decreases as the run time increases dramatically since the run time is proportional to the square of the input. The O(n^2)-time method is more efficient than the O(n log n)-time method only for very small amounts of input (in this case for inputs less than 100), but as the input grows larger (in this case 100 or larger), the O(n log n) becomes the much more efficient method.

Am I only stating what is obvious and presented in the question or does the answer seem to satisfy the question?

Comment: Did that class cover a formal definition of big Oh?

Answer (score 2):

You noted in your answer that to be O(N^2), the run-time is *proportional* to the square of the size of the input. Follow up on that -- there is a constant of proportionality which is present but not described by big-O notation. For actual timings, the magnitudes of the constants matter.

Big-O also ignores lower order terms, since asymptotically they are dominated by the highest order term, but those lower order terms still contribute to the actual timings.

As a consequence of either (or both) of these issues, a function which has a higher growth rate can nevertheless have a smaller outcome for a limited range of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

No, I think this is not enough.

I would expect an answer to explain how the big-oh definition allows a function `f(x) > g(x)`, for some x, even if `O(f(x)) < O(g(x))`. There a formalism that would answer it in two lines.

Another option is to answer it more intuitively, explaining how the constant term of the time function plays a fundamental role in small input sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct if you consider input explicitly i.e., n<=100 and so on. But actually asymptotic analysis( big O, omega etc) is done for considerable large inputs, like when n tends to infinite. nlogn is efficient than n^2. This statement is true when n is sufficiently large. We talk about big-oh without considering the input size. This means asymtotic analysis by default assumes input size is very large. We ignore specific values of n considering them as machine dependent. That is the reason why constants are ignored( as n approaches sufficient large , effect of constants becomes negligible)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct as far as it goes but it does not mention how or why this can happen. One explanation is that there is a fixed amount of (extra) overhead with the O(n log n)-time method such that the total benefit of the method doesn't add up to equal/exceed the overhead until 100 such benefits have aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

By definition:

T(n) is O(f(n)) if and only if exists two constants C and n0 that:
T(n) < Cf(n) when n > n0.

In your cases this means that coefficients before n^2 is smaller than before nlogn or asymptotic limits  can be acquired on n > 100.